# Jenkins Job DSL: unknown return statement

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

some days ago I bumped into a code snippet used to override the default configuration of the Jenkins plugin "GitHub SCM Source" (unknown author):

```
Closure configOverride(String repo, int id, String cred) {
return {    
    it / sources / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' << {
        source(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource') {    
            id(id)    
            scanCredentialsId(cred)    
            checkoutCredentialsId('SAME')    
            repoOwner('owner')    
            repository(repo) 
            includes('*')    
            buildOriginBranch('true')    
            buildOriginBranchWithPR('true')    
            buildOriginPRMerge('false')    
            buildOriginPRHead('false')    
            buildForkPRMerge('true')    
            buildForkPRHead('false')    
         }
      }
   }
}
```

All it's good except that I can't understand the following line:

```
it / sources / 'data' / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' << { ... }
```

I tried to find some explanation about the use of '/' in groovy but no luck. Maybe I don't know what exactly to search.

Could someone help me please with a link to the docs or a short explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet is used in Jenkins DSL for the "multibranchPipelineJob". The closure configOverride is used to generate an XML object which replace the default configuration in config.xml on the following path "sources/data/jenkins.branch.BranchSource".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is [overloading of
operators](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading)

> Groovy allows you to overload the various operators so that they can be used with your own classes. Consider this simple class:
>
> ```
> class Bucket {
>     int size
>
>     Bucket(int size) { this.size = size }
>
>     Bucket plus(Bucket other) {                     
>         return new Bucket(this.size + other.size)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Just by implementing the plus() method, the Bucket class can now be used with the + operator like so:
>
> ```
> def b1 = new Bucket(4)
> def b2 = new Bucket(11)
> assert (b1 + b2).size == 15
> ```

For `/` one would override `T div(T x)`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is not the case, I just found the response to my question.